# SQL - How To Order Using Count From Another Table

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-order-by

**1. Bloggers**

```
blogger_id
1 
2
3
```

**2. Posts**

```
post_from_blogger_id
1 
1
1
2
2
3
```

As you can see blogger №1 posted more than the others and blogger №3 less. The question **is
how to build a query that selects all bloggers and sorts them by the number of their posts?**

Answer (score 55, accepted):

```
 SELECT bloggers.*, COUNT(post_id) AS post_count
    FROM bloggers LEFT JOIN blogger_posts 
    ON bloggers.blogger_id = blogger_posts.blogger_id
    GROUP BY bloggers.blogger_id
    ORDER BY post_count
```

(Note: MySQL has special syntax that lets you GROUP BY without aggregating all values, it's intended for exactly this situation).

Comment: Which is the special syntax?

Comment: The special syntax, shown in my example, is that unlike standard SQL you do *not* have to include all the non-aggregated columns from the SELECT clause in the GROUP BY clause.  In standard SQL, you would not be able to use bloggers.* in the SELECT part.

Answer (score 4):

Use subqueries.

```
select * from (
    select post_from_blogger_id, count(1) N from Posts
    group by post_from_blogger_id) t
order by N desc
```

Comment: The subquery isn't necessary.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. These answers didn't help me. I used such a query:

```
SELECT *
FROM company c
ORDER BY (select count(a.company_id) from asset a where a.company_id = c.id) DESC
```

To this question:

```
SELECT *
FROM bloggers b
ORDER BY (select count(p.post_from_blogger_id) from posts p where p.post_from_blogger_id = b.blogger_id) DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT B.blogger_id,
       B.blogger_name,
       IFNULL(COUNT(P.post_from_blogger_id ),0) AS NumPosts 
From Blogger AS B
LEFT JOIN Posts AS P ON P.post_from_blogger_id = B.blogger_id
GROUP BY B.blogger_id, B.blogger_name
ORDER BY COUNT(P.post_from_blogger_id ) DESC
```

This joins the 2 tables, and counts the number of entries in the `Posts` table. If there are none, then the count is 0 ([`IFNULL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull)).

Comment: Do you really need the IFNULL?  Shouldn't COUNT be returning 0 if no non-NULL post_from_blogger_id values are encountered?

Comment: Now that you've added the GROUP BY, you can take advantage of MySQL and include only blogger_id in the list of grouped-by columns.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT b.*
FROM Bloggers AS b
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT post_from_blogger_id, COUNT(*) AS post_count
  FROM Posts
  GROUP BY post_from_blogger_id
) AS p ON b.blogger_id = p.post_from_blogger_id
ORDER BY p.post_count DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

try LEFT JOIN for this question

```
SELECT DISTINCT(Bloggers.blogger_id),
(select  count(post_from_blogger_id) from Posts 
where Posts.post_from_blogger_id=Bloggers.blogger_id) post_from_blogger_id FROM Bloggers 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Posts ON Bloggers.blogger_id=Posts.post_from_blogger_id 
ORDER BY post_from_blogger_id DESC
```