# SQL select and order by (count of related records inside a second table) subtracted by (count of related records inside second table with condition)

Tags: sql, select, group-by, case, sql-order-by

I am trying to **SELECT** every record in a table one **ORDER**ed **BY** the **COUNT** of records inside a second table that store the related primary key value and **WHERE** 'positive' is true, subtracted by the **COUNT** of records inside the second table that store the related primary key value and **WHERE** 'positive' is false.

Here is my database structure

Table 1

| id | data |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | zero |
| 1 | one |
| 2 | two |
| 3 | three |

Table 2

| id | related_tableone_id | positive |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | 3 | 1 |
| 5 | 3 | 1 |

Here is what I am trying to get

| id | data | subtracted_counts (i dont need this but these values are what the records should be ordered by) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | three | 2 |
| 2 | two | 1 |
| 0 | zero | 0 |
| 1 | one | -1 |

*For better understanding on what i want to achieve:* 
This database structure can be compared with a **voting system**, where
Table 1 are entities that can be **voted up** or **voted down**. 
In this case, Table 2 would store the votes with **positive=true** for an **upvote** and **positive=false** for a **downvote**. 
The goal is to get all entities **ORDER**ed **BY** their summarized **vote value**. 
(Within a single query)

**My research**

I found this post
[SQL - How To Order Using Count From Another Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784545/sql-how-to-order-using-count-from-another-table), tho there is no subtraction logic

I tried this query

```
SELECT 
    tableone.*, 
    COUNT(related_tableone_id) - COUNT(negative_related_tableone_id) AS subtracted_count
FROM 
    tableone 
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT related_tableone_id 
     FROM tabletwo 
     WHERE positive = true) AS positives ON tableone.id = positives.related_tableone_id
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT related_tableone_id AS negative_related_tableone_id 
     FROM tabletwo 
     WHERE positive = false) AS negatives ON tableone.id = negatives.negative_related_tableone_id
GROUP BY 
    tableone.id
ORDER BY 
    subtracted_count DESC;
```

But it doesn't subtract the counts right for some reason and there is probably a more clear solution

Comment: *but under different conditions* what conditions? Under "Here is what i am trying to get" you present a column labeled "i dont need this". Edit your question and clarify what you want.

Comment: If tabletwo.positive were -1 and 1 instead of 0 and 1, you could ORDER BY SUM(positive).

Comment: @StefanSchmiedl That is a great idea. Unfortunately in my case it is important that the 'positive' column stores boolean values.

Comment: how using something like `iif(positive=0,-1,1)`?

Comment: Can you explain why subtracted_counts for id=2 is 1?

Comment: @forpas Of course. In Table 2 there are three records with related_tableone_id=2. Two of them are positive, one is not -> 2-1 = 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `LEFT` join of `Table1` to `Table2` and conditional aggregation in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.data       
FROM Table1 t1 LEFT JOIN Table2 t2
ON t2.related_tableone_id = t1.id
GROUP BY t1.id
ORDER BY SUM(CASE t2.positive WHEN true THEN 1 WHEN false THEN -1 ELSE 0 END) DESC;
```

or, a correlated subquery in the `ORDER BY` clause (which may perform better):

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM Table1 t1
ORDER BY (
  SELECT COALESCE(SUM(CASE t2.positive WHEN true THEN 1 WHEN false THEN -1 END) , 0)
  FROM Table2 t2 
  WHERE t2.related_tableone_id = t1.id
) DESC;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/KjX-grJx) (works in MySql, Postgresql and SQLite).

Comment: Thank you very much! For people that would like to also display the subtracted_counts (not in my case so its the perfect answer), the upper query can be slightly modified by replacing `SELECT t1.id, t1.data, SUM(CASE t2.positive WHEN true THEN 1 WHEN false THEN -1 ELSE 0 END) as subtracted_counts` and `ORDER BY subtracted_counts DESC;`

Answer (score 1):

A single subquery can count both upvotes and downvotes, using conditional aggregation. I would use a lateral join to do the computation:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from tableone t1
cross join lateral (
    select 
        sum(case when t2.positive = true  then 1 else 0 end) upvotes,
        sum(case when t2.positive = false then 1 else 0 end) downvotes
    from tabletwo t2
    where t2.related_tableone_id = t1.id
) t2
order by t2.upvotes - t2.downvotes desc, t1.id
```

Depending on your database, the lateral join might be introduced by `cross apply`instead (eg in Oracle or SQL Server).